# Drools - Business Central workbench Alternative

Tags: drools, dmn

Currently we are using Drools -business central workbench and its used by business users to manage the rules . Effective version 8 , business central is retired so how are we looking forward business users to author rules , provided the fact they are not comfortable to use Eclipse IDE / VS Code editors.
What are the other options through which business users can still author DMN decisions ?

What are the other options through which business users can still author DMN decisions (chrome extensions blocked in our organization )

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is seeking recommendations for tools. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

As your target audience seems to be Business Analyst, SME and stakeholders, possibly the [KIE Sandbox](https://sandbox.kie.org) is best suited for this purpose.

That sandbox is just a way to conveniently run the editors in your local browser (ie the models will be edited and saved locally unless you decide to push the models somewhere remote).

The KIE tools used to offer similar solution to sandbox which could be spin up on premise, but I'm not sure what's the status on that effort you might best check with the KIE/Kogito community forum.